Azure Functions: Errors after migration to isolated process
We've migrated from in process model to isolated, and from .NET 6 to .NET 8. The API is up and running but I can see occasionally some errors in the logs.
The function is a simple health check method, just to see if the API is up.
[Function(nameof(HealthCheck))]
public ActionResult<string> HealthCheck([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "HealthCheck/a4a68a59-8563-4e32-9bef-7660321f68fb")] HttpRequest req)
{
    return new OkObjectResult("OK");
}

99% of the time it works fine, but sometimes we get this error:

Call Stack: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore.DefaultHttpCoordinator+<SetFunctionContextAsync>d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=551316b6919f366c: D:\a\_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore\src\Coordinator\DefaultHttpCoordinator.cs:35) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore.FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext
(Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore,
Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=551316b6919f366c:
D:\a_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore\src\FunctionsMiddleware\FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.cs:41)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication+d__10.MoveNext
(Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Core, Version=1.17.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=551316b6919f366c:
D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:77) ,
Message: A task was canceled.

And

Call Stack: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__26.MoveNext
(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:352)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:108) Inner exception Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker+d__9.MoveNext
(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.31.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null:
/_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs:101)    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase+<Invoke>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.31.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionInvokerBase.cs:82)    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionGenerator+d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.31.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionGenerator.cs:225)    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:52) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__33.MoveNext
(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:581)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__32.MoveNext
(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:527)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult
(System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__26.MoveNext
(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:306)
, Message: Exception while executing function: Functions.HealthCheck


The only thing that sticks out for me is that the System.Private.CoreLib package is version 8.0.0.0 in the first exception, and 6.0.0.0 in the underlying one. It feels like I've missed something in the migration.


Call Stack: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException

This could be due timeout or a cancellation of an asynchronous operation.
To resolve this error, use functionTimeout attribute in host.json and debug the function:
host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
  "functionTimeout": "00:30:00"
}

I have tested the same code with .NET 8 Isolated Azure function in my environment:
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route ="ready")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult("ok");
        }
    }

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Able to test without any issues:


Update the packages to the latest compatible versions:


